# FragmentActivity inside a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am new to android and i have some questions.  I created a simple layout with two fragments such as follow:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

I want to divide this layout as follow :

layout_height of fragment1 : 1/3 height

layout_height of fragment2 : 2/3 height

How can do it?

I used below code to show fragment1 :

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.add(R.id.fragment1, firstfragment);
```

But I don't know how to show FragmentActivity in fragment2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can achive this layout like this

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3"
     >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in java you must call commit in transaction

//to add Fragment1

FragmentTransaction transaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment1, firstfragment).commit();

// to add Fragment2

```
FragmentTransaction transaction1 =
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction1.add(R.id.fragment2, secondfragment).commit;
```

and you can not put any activity inside Fragments. but you can start another activity from your fragments

Answer (score 0):

To put two elements in some ratio - use LinearLayout then set height of contained views to 0dp and add layoutWeight attributes in desired ratio (for example 1 and 2 in your case)
To instantiate fragments just use code as you written twice. You omitted  the `transaction.commit();` part. You have to cal this twice - once for every fragment you want to add.

Question about adding FragmentActivity is misleading - you can't put Activity into Fragment, you only can insert Fragment(s) into Activities.